# Register Model in mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

How do I register a model in mongoengine?

I know that in other extensions like in mongokit you can do the following:

```
db.register([Task])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that. It will be registered automatically to db as soon as it detected in your python application context.